# Application Icon is not displaying in task bar when we publish a winform application in server

Tags: c#, winforms, icons

Please suggest me a way to achieve Icon in taskbar when my windows forms application in published in server.I have tried by adding icon in **Properties->Application->Resources ->Icon and Manifest** but its not working for me.Please suggest me a way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Taskbar icon is not tied to your application; it is tied to your active form instead - so set properly icon on your form(s). The icon on application is for shell (i.e. when you open via explorer folder in which your app lies).